# Looking for most reliable and compatible (with other Drupal modules) multiple photo uploader and gallery system in Drupal 6 and Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, media, files

DrupalGardens hosted (Drupal 7) sites use a fantastically easy multiple photo uploader - i.e. one can select multiple image files from an Explorer Browser box (or other OS equivalent) using CTRL, SHIFT and upload them all at once into a gallery.

Question 1) What modules is this based on, so that I can export and deploy a site outside of DrupalGardens?

More importantly:

Question 2) If I was building a Drupal 7 site from scratch with my own hosting, what modules would I need to achieve this?

Question 3) If I was building a Drupal 6 site from scratch with my own hosting, what modules would I need to achieve this?

I wish to stay with Drupal 7 in my consideration as to which version to use. But if Drupal 6 has more rich functionality then I may use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use [Media Library](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) on Drupal garden but this is only for D7 and it's still in dev. You can also try [Cincopa](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) which is really interesting, it's for D6 but they are developping a D7 version

Comment: +1 and Accepted Answer. Answers all 3 of my questions. Media Library "only for D7" - that's OK: that's the answer I was looking for in 1) and 2). Cincopa answers 3). Media Library "it's still in dev" - isn't ALL software? Software is never finished, it is only released. It's at beta so should be fine. Well it works great in Drupal Gardens so should work well on D7 elsewhere - I will report back. Even some alpha quality modules work well.

Comment: Be aware this is not always the case.  The tags mean different things for different developpers, but most developpers agree alpha means "work in progress".